# Laravel 5.4 redirect to modal after validation

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, laravel-5.4

I have a form in modal, I want to redirect to the modal with all the errors, but it does not seem to work, here is my validator in the controller

```
   $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'company' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'description' => 'required|string|max:300',
        'engineers' => 'required',
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
    }
```

Here is my jquery in the blade view where my modal is activated

```
 @if (count($errors) > 0)
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
    $('#create').modal('show');   
</script>
@endif
```

the prototype of my modal

```
<div class="modal fade container" id="createProject">
   {!! Form::open([ 'route' => 'projects.store']) !!}
        <div class="modal-content" id="create">
    @if($errors->has())
        @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
            <div>{{ $error }}</div>
        @endforeach
    @endif
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Create Project</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
```

what happens is that after validation fails, it just redirects back to the view where it was called but I have to click again to trigger the modal

Comment: try changing the id in the jquery to createProject and check

Comment: Instead of Submitting form and redirect back to form and display modal. this process is very long just use AJAX that will send request on background and you don't need to show modal after submission because it happens in background.

Answer (score 1):

Change this part:

```
 @if (count($errors) > 0)
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
    $('#create').modal('show');   
</script>
@endif
```

To

```
 @if (count($errors) > 0)
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

$(document).ready(function(){

 $('#create').modal('show'); 

});
@endif
```

Why not submit the form with AJAX and return the error while the modal is still open.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
$('#create').modal('show');
```

to this line

```
 (function($){
       $('#createProject').modal('show');  
    })($);
```

`id` you are using to show model is wrong here. And you are calling model open which may not work if DOM is not ready yet. So change line with above code, and it should work just fine.